# New Swap Drive - Linux Hangs during Boot

Tags: linux, lvm, boot, swap, fstab

An application checked the swap space during install and required it to be the same amount as ram. So i added a new disk (Server is a VM) and done the following:

```
swapoff /dev/mapper/ol-swap
vgcreate swap /dev/sdc
lvcreate --name swap -l 100%FREE swap
mkswap /dev/mapper/swap-swap
swapon /dev/mapper/swap-swap
lvremove /dev/ol/swap
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ol/root
```

After that i changed the swap entry in fstab. I tought i was done, so i rebooted to check everything was fine. But the reboot fails with the error message

```
dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timout scripts
[...]
Warning: /dev/ol/swap does not exists
```

Any ideas where i have to delete the old swap locations?

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to also adjust /etc/fstab with the new info?

Delete or comment the old swap partition and add the new one.